# How do I design dynamodb table for a given set of relational tables

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have set of 3 relational tables. I want to convert them to a single table in dynamodb. Each table hosts data for different tranType. Each table has Id, tranDate as its key. For a given Id, tranDate and tranType, there are multiple rows.

My access pattern is get data for a given Id and TranDate - which will get me data for all tranTypes.

Rows in each table is within 400KB for a given Id, tranDate, but if I add rows for a given Id and tranDate across 3 tables, it will exceed 400KB.

```
Definitions
Table1
Id, tranDate,tranType,col1,col2,col3,col4
Table2
Id, tranDate,tranType,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
Table3
Id, tranDate,tranType,col1,col2 

Table1 (Sample Data)
1, 2018-12-01,'DETAIL',12,13,14,'A'
1, 2018-12-01,'DETAIL',15,23,11,'B'
1, 2018-12-01,'DETAIL',17,33,24,'C'
1, 2018-12-01,'DETAIL',19,43,14,'D'
2, 2018-12-01,'DETAIL',11,13,14,'A1'
2, 2018-12-01,'DETAIL',12,23,11,'B1' 
1, 2018-11-01,'DETAIL',42,13,14,'X'
1, 2018-11-01,'DETAIL',45,23,11,'Y'
1, 2018-11-01,'DETAIL',47,33,24,'Z'

Table2 (Sample Data)
1, 2018-12-01,'SUMMARY',12,13,14,'A','S'
1, 2018-12-01,'SUMMARY',15,23,11,'B','B1'
2, 2018-12-01,'SUMMARY',17,33,24,'C','D1'
2, 2018-12-01,'SUMMARY',22,43,14,'D','D2'
2, 2018-12-01,'SUMMARY',33,13,14,'A1' ,'D3'

Table3 (Sample Data)
1, 2018-12-01,'GEO',11,'MI'
1, 2018-12-01,'GEO',12,'NY'
1, 2018-12-01,'GEO',11,'AL'
2, 2018-12-01,'GEO',14,'DE'
2, 2018-12-01,'GEO',15,'PA'
```

Given Id=1, tranDate='2018-12-01' -- Expected Results

```
1, 2018-12-01,'DETAIL',12,13,14,'A'
1, 2018-12-01,'DETAIL',15,23,11,'B'
1, 2018-12-01,'DETAIL',17,33,24,'C'
1, 2018-12-01,'DETAIL',19,43,14,'D' 

1, 2018-12-01,'SUMMARY',12,13,14,'A','S'
1, 2018-12-01,'SUMMARY',15,23,11,'B','B1' 

1, 2018-12-01,'GEO',11,'MI'
1, 2018-12-01,'GEO',12,'NY'
1, 2018-12-01,'GEO',11,'AL'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, one possible design would be to use the concatenation of id + date as the partition key, and use the transaction type as the sort key, possibly combining the sort key with one of the other ids.

So, your table might look like this:

```
 PK             |  TranType         |       data        
----------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------
"1:2018-12-01"  |  "DETAIL"         | ["12,13,14,A", "15,23,11,B",...]
"1:2018-12-01"  |  "SUMMARY"        | ["12,13,14,A,S", "15,23,11,B,B1"]
"1:2018-12-01"  |  "GEO"            | ["11,MI", "12,NY", "11,AL"]
"2:2018-12-01"  |  "DETAIL"         | [...] 
"2:2018-12-01"  |  "SUMMARY"        | [...] 
"2:2018-12-01"  |  "GEO"            | [...]
```

Assuming the data payload is not too big that will work.

Another possibility would be to further break down the data into discrete attributes and creating a composite column for the sort key, formed from the transaction type prefix and one of the ids in the data, or just a numeric index (this really depends on what those other columns in your example really mean).

An example, assuming the `col1` is unique for detail and summary, might look like this:

```
 PK             |  TTID             | states      | c2 | c3 | c4  | c5 |     
----------------+-------------------+-------------+----+----+-----+----+--
"1:2018-12-01"  |  "DETAIL:12"      |             | 13 | 14 | 'A' 
"1:2018-12-01"  |  "DETAIL:15"      |             | 23 | 11 | 'B' 
"1:2018-12-01"  |  "DETAIL:17"      |             | 33 | 24 | 'C' 
"1:2018-12-01"  |  "DETAIL:19"      |             | 43 | 14 | 'D' 
"1:2018-12-01"  |  "SUMMARY:12"     |             | 13 | 14 | 'A' | 'S'
"1:2018-12-01"  |  "SUMMARY:15"     |             | 23 | 11 | 'B' | 'B1'
"1:2018-12-01"  |  "GEO:11"         | ["MI","AL"] |
"1:2018-12-01"  |  "GEO:12"         | ["NY"]      |
"2:2018-12-01"  |  "DETAIL:11"      |             | 13 |14  | A1 
"2:2018-12-01"  |  "DETAIL:.."      |             |    ...  
"2:2018-12-01"  |  "SUMMARY:17"     |             |    ...  
"2:2018-12-01"  |  "SUMMARY:.."     |             |    ... 
"2:2018-12-01"  |  "GEO:.."         |  ...        |
```

There is not one single answer to this question. Design the schema based on the data that you have and how you access your data.